# I need POP up window after IF and ELSE statement

Tags: php, popup

I need pop up window after IF and Else statement heres my code.

```
else if ($selected_radio=='q1yes' && $status=='yes' && $bus=='retail' && $retail=='retailyes' && $phonetype=='dsl' && $checks=='checkyes'    ) {
$q1yes_status = 'checked';
$yes_status = 'checked';
$service_status='checked';
$autorepair_status='checked';
$analog_status='checked';
$checkyes_status='checked';
echo "your answer is yes yes retail autorepair dsl yes"; <<<< --- that text should change pop up window URL like "http://formsignup.php" instead of text message. I'm not sure if that possible to do Pop up inside ECHO.
```

I appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

echo some javascript code, then when the page sis sent to the browser the browser will fire the javascript code causing your popup to show:

```
echo "<script>alert('your answer is yes yes retail autorepair dsl yes');</script>";
```

for example:

Comment: you are forgetting the script tags =)

Answer (score 1):

Would the POP up window be done is JavaScript?

So where you wanted a POP up window you could echo/print the required JavaScript?

Using code like...

```
window.open("http://formsignup.php","Window Name",width=430,height=360");
```

This code could be included in the HEAD of the document, and then called in the main BODY.

Or this could all be put in the BODY like...

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.open("http://formsignup.php","Window Name",width=430,height=360");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. i will try to implement your suggestion.thank you very much.

Comment: Give me a shout if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo some javascript that loads a new window?

```
echo "<script>window.open('url to open','window name');</script>";
```